# Sql - set the same parameter value in loop

Tags: c#, sql, loops, parameters

I need to declare parameter once and then use it several times with Insert query like:

```
SqlCommand mainCMD = new SqlCommand("", conn);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    mainCMD.CommandText += "INSERT INTO Country (name) VALUES (@cntr)";
    mainCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cntr", "Country" + i);
}
mainCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Looks like you are doing a lot of thing wrong. First of all, you adding `mainCMD.CommandText` 5 times to itself.

Comment: Yes, that's just non working example - just wanted to show what I'd like to reach.

Answer (score 3):

You should change name of parameter

```
SqlCommand mainCMD = new SqlCommand("", conn);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   mainCMD.CommandText += 
       String.Format(" INSERT INTO Country (name) VALUES (@cntr{0})", i);
   mainCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cntr" + i, "Country" + i);
}
```

Also it will be more efficient to build command text separately:

```
int countriesCount = 5;

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();      
for(int i = 0; i < countriesCount; i++)
    builder.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO Country (name) VALUES (@cntr{0}) ", i);

var cmd = new SqlCommand(builder.ToString(), conn);
for (int i = 0; i < countriesCount; i++)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cntr" + i, "Country" + i);
```

Comment: I like the second example, I'd probably only use one for loop though

Answer (score 2):

Just use mainCMD.**Parameters.clear()** at the end of the loop

```
SqlCommand mainCMD = new SqlCommand("", conn);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    mainCMD.CommandText += "INSERT INTO Country (name) VALUES (@cntr)";
    mainCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cntr", "Country" + i);
    mainCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
    mainCMD.Parameters.clear();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build your command and parameter ONCE, then just change the parameter value IN the loop

```
SqlCommand mainCMD = new SqlCommand( " INSERT INTO Country (name) VALUES (@parmCountry)", conn);
// just to prime the parameter with proper data type string expectation
mainCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parmCountry", "test country");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   // change ONLY the parameter, then execute it
   mainCMD.Parameters[0].Value = "Country" + i.ToString();
   mainCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```